# Not Able to upload Picture on ng2-Cloudinary?

Tags: angular, cloudinary

I have given both cloudName as well as uploadPreset .but it showing both cloud name as well as uploadPreset but not uploading the file.when i am uploading picture

Comment: what you have tried, any code samples or  any error?

Comment: ya i tried alot ...

Comment: uploader: CloudinaryUploader = new CloudinaryUploader(
        new CloudinaryOptions({ cloudName: 'pietechsolutions', uploadPreset: 't0iey0lk' })
    );

    constructor() {
           this.uploader.onAfterAddingFile = (item: any) => {
            item.url = this.uploader.options.url;
            console.log("url is" + item.url);
            return item;
        };
        this.uploader.onSuccessItem = (item: any, response: string, status: number, headers: any): any => {
            return { item, response, status, headers };
        };
    }

Comment: i am sucessfully upload with sample image

Comment: https://ekito.github.io/ng2-cloudinary/demo/ here is the online link

Comment: try with your name and preset its working perfectly

Comment: https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/solutions/auto/upload  this is the reponse i m getting on  this.uploader.onAfterAddingFile this fuction

Comment: just download the plugin demo file run locally.and implement what you want the demo works perfectly.i think you missed something!!!

Comment: i have done with everything but not getting response on this.uploader.onSuccessItem

Comment: will you tell me how can i check cloudName and uploadPreset is working or not

Comment: which version you are using for ng2-cloudinary

Comment: i can upload image using your cloud name and preset

Comment: https://ekito.github.io/ng2-cloudinary/demo/

Comment: goto this url scrool down and check your cloudname and preset are properly working or not

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B733yfEiKOnUamVOYTRsdGZ1aDQ/view